# Manage env files for load balanced scaling groups

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elb

I am using aws elb for auto scaling my backend servers.
Right now I fetch my environment variables from .env file from the root of my project.
Every time I update the env variables I have to update the user config in the launch configuration of my auto scaling group.
Or if I am using an AMI I have to update the AMI. I want to know if there is a better way to do this.
I am using nodejs for my backend.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using `AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store`?

Comment: Thanks, I am considering using Amazon secrets manager for this

Answer (score 0):

The proper cloudian way of doing things would be to pull the variables at runtime from [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) or [Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) (depending on the required scope of security management for the variables)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, it is recommended to use environment variable from [AWS SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) or [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/).

Note: They both seem similar, however Secrets Manager has the ability to rotate the secrets.